# MySQL self join to find only the next revision

Tags: mysql, sql, self-join

Actually I'm working with Wordpress. I want to create a self-join or something similar to find a revision of a post, and the following revision of the same post.

```
create table wp_posts (post_id int, revision_id int);
INSERT INTO wp_posts(post_id, revision_id) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO wp_posts(post_id, revision_id) VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO wp_posts(post_id, revision_id) VALUES (1, 3);

INSERT INTO wp_posts(post_id, revision_id) VALUES (2, 11);
INSERT INTO wp_posts(post_id, revision_id) VALUES (2, 12);
INSERT INTO wp_posts(post_id, revision_id) VALUES (2, 13);

SELECT a.post_id, a.revision_id "PreviousRevision", b.revision_id "FollowingRevision"
  FROM `wp_posts` a
  JOIN `wp_posts` b
    ON a.post_id = b.post_id   #the id of every revision of a post is different but the post_id is the same
 WHERE a.revision_id < b.revision_id
 AND a.revision_id != b.revision_id
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eHnwYABYrVVQAhn8xLJ77q/1

The previous query doesn't work since it takes, for every record of a, all the revision which have been made and not just the next one.

This is what I get, and I've striked out the lines I don't want. I need only father-child rows.

[image]

How can I take just one element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this sample data you need the maximum `a.revision_id` for each combination of `a.post_id, b.revision_id`:

```
SELECT 
  a.post_id, 
  MAX(a.revision_id) "PreviousRevision", 
  b.revision_id "FollowingRevision"
FROM `wp_posts` a JOIN `wp_posts` b
ON a.post_id = b.post_id   
WHERE a.revision_id < b.revision_id
GROUP BY a.post_id, b.revision_id
```

Also the condition `a.revision_id != b.revision_id` is not necessary beacause you already have `a.revision_id < b.revision_id`.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eHnwYABYrVVQAhn8xLJ77q/2).
Results:

```
| post_id | PreviousRevision | FollowingRevision |
| ------- | ---------------- | ----------------- |
| 1       | 1                | 2                 |
| 1       | 2                | 3                 |
| 2       | 11               | 12                |
| 2       | 12               | 13                |
```

Comment: Thanks, I cannot understand why the group by works.. can you help me?

Comment: In this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eHnwYABYrVVQAhn8xLJ77q/3 you can see the results without GROUP BY. As you can see for each combination of a.post_id, b.revision_id you want in the results the maximum value of a.revision_id. This is what GROUP BY and MAX do.

Comment: really smart solution

Answer (score 4):

In MySQL 8+, you would use window functions:

```
SELECT p.post_id, p.revision_id,
       lag(p.revision_id) over (partition by p.post_id order by p.revision_id) as prev_revision_id,
       lead(p.revision_id) over (partition by p.post_id order by p.revision_id) as next_revision_id
FROM `wp_posts` p;
```

In earlier versions, I would use a correlated subquery:

```
select p.post_id, p.revision_id,
       (select max(p2.revision_id)
        from wp_posts p2
        where p2.post_id = p.post_id and p2.revision_id < p.revision_id
       ) as prev_revision_id,
       (select min(p2.revision_id)
        from wp_posts p2
        where p2.post_id = p.post_id and p2.revision_id > p.revision_id
       ) as next_revision_id
from wp_posts p;
```

Comment: I can't accept both the answers but this is also really great

Comment: @Revious . . . The version using using window functions is definitely more performant.  I would expect the correlated subqueries to be faster than an aggregation solution as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use the query from @forpas with group by as I do not like how explain of the query looks like (temporary + filesort).

I'm usually doing something like this in such situations:

```
SELECT 
    a.post_id
  , a.revision_id "PrevRevision"
  , b.revision_id "NextRevision"
FROM
    `wp_posts` AS a
    INNER JOIN `wp_posts` AS b ON (
            b.post_id = a.post_id
        AND b.revision_id > a.revision_id
    )
    LEFT JOIN `wp_posts` AS c ON (
            c.post_id = a.post_id
        AND c.revision_id > a.revision_id
        AND c.revision_id < b.revision_id
    )
WHERE
    c.revision_id IS NULL
```

Explain with index (post_id, revision_id) on the table:

```
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE  a       index   IX_wp_post_idx  IX_wp_post_idx  10      6   100.00  Using where; Using index
1   SIMPLE  b       ref IX_wp_post_idx  IX_wp_post_idx  5   test.a.post_id  4   33.33   Using where; Using index
1   SIMPLE  c       ref IX_wp_post_idx  IX_wp_post_idx  5   test.a.post_id  4   16.67   Using where; Using index
```

On some data sets query subquery (suggested by @Gordon Linoff) would be faster.